# Google+ Sign-In Error: invalid_request

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth

Its been working properly for a while but just now I'm getting the following error and couldn't find anything to figure that out.

When I click on the Google Sign-In I get this error message from Google.

This is my google render()

```
function render() {
gapi.signin.render('customBtn', {
  'callback': 'onSignInCallback',
  'clientid': '317162416761.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
  'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
  'scope': 'openid email profile'
});
```

}

[image]

I've also notice now that I get a 400 (Bad Request) when calling Google oauth2

[image]

This is the URL call: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=317162416761.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code%20token%20id_token%20gsession&scope=openid%20email%20profile&request_visible_actions=http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.google.com%2FAddActivity&cookie_policy=single_host_origin&immediate=true&proxy=oauth2relay720963522&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fmmaprophet.com&state=544595189%7C0.866765767&authuser=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing older OAuth 2.0 scopes with newer Google+ features. Updating to the [latest scopes](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes) should work.

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`

Comment: Thanks million time.  Strange that it use to work previously.